# Optaplanner, earliest job start time

Tags: job-scheduling, optaplanner

**Problem**: I am trying to schedule multiple SKUs across 3-4 sequential activities for optimal scheduling under constrained resources.

**Tool**: Optaplanner job scheduler

**Issue**: Each activity has a predecessor (which is not being modelled) and can only start after the predecessor is complete. So each job can start only after a pre-defined X hours.

**Question**: How to provide this X-hours as an input to the job scheduler?

Comment: This question is vague. It's unclear what has already been tried. Try improving the question so it's faster to read than it was to write.

Comment: IIRC the Project Job Scheduling example in OptaPlanner has a similar sounding constraint. See it's video on youtube and the docs chapter 3.